# module import error for deferred tasks in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue, deferred

I'm creating task using deferred.defer. The tasks fail with the following error.

```
Permanent failure attempting to execute task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 298, in post
  self.run_from_request()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 293, in run_from_request
  run(self.request.body)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 133, in run
raise PermanentTaskFailure(e)
PermanentTaskFailure: cannot import name location
```

location is a module in our source code.

**Additional details:**

I also have third party libraries in folder lib. I have file third_party_libs.py

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))
```

I include this file in relevant places. I have also tried including this in all __init__.py files. The Error is particularly cryptic and does stack trace doesn't point to any location in my source
Any pointers on how to debug this will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show how you are creating the deferred task.

Comment: something like this

    deferred.defer(harmonize_square, str_param1, str_param2, str_param2, _queue="harmonize")


Note that all params are one word strings like names, ids

Comment: The deffered function is defined in the same module and the module is not a RequestHandler

Comment: doesn't feel like a third-party lib problem. did you search already on SO for similar problems? some posts show that it may depend on the order you're loading the modules required by the deferred task (thus it doesn't find them), so you may want to dig SO a bit

Comment: I have looked at different posts. Tried a few things the problem goes away for a few days, and I think I have fixed it. But it reappears. Probably something to do with spawning of new app engine instance - it seems to be intermittent. My problem is I don't know how to start debugging this problem to find out what the fix is. And its frustrating to keep trying random things without understanding what the problem is.

Comment: Maybe you have a circulair import / namespace problem. Make sure you only import modules and not the only the deferred task function from the module.

Comment: The deferred call and the deferred function  are in the same module.